# Google Maps API for Android in a WallpaperService (live wallpaper)

Tags: android, maps, live-wallpaper

Is there a way to use the Google Maps API for Android in a Live Wallpaper? From looking at the API, mapViews seem to require a MapActivity, so I'm not sure if there an easy way to make this work in a WallpaperService out of the box.

Comment: i've seen a live wallpaper that is google maps - don't know how it works.